# Is there a notion of embeddedness for measurable spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

Let $(E_i,\mathcal E_i)$ be a measurable space. We say that $(E_1,\mathcal E_1)$ and $(E_2,\mathcal E_2)$ are isomorphic if there is a measurable bijection $(E_1,\mathcal E_1)\to(E_2,\mathcal E_2)$.

> Is there a related notion of $(E_1,\mathcal E_1)$ being *embedded* into $(E_2,\mathcal E_2)$?

I've seen that some authors say that $(E_1,\mathcal E_1)$ is embedded into $(E_2,\mathcal E_2)$ if $E_1\subseteq E_2$ and $\mathcal E_1=\left\{E_1\cap B_2:B_2\in\mathcal E_2\right\}$.

On the other hand, in light of the definition of being isomorphic, we might require the existence of a measurable injection $(E_1,\mathcal E_1)\to(E_2,\mathcal E_2)$.

However, the example I've got in mind is the following: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces. Then the space of measurable functions $(E,\mathcal E)\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ seems to be "naturally embedded" into the space of measurable functions $(\Omega\times E,\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal E)\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. But the mapping yielding this "embedding" is $\Omega\times E\ni(\omega,x)\mapsto x$ which is surjective, not injective.

Comment: I would rather say that the mapping yielding this "embedding" is something like $f\mapsto\hat f$ where $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is a measurable function and $\hat f:\Omega\times E\to\mathbb R$ is a measurable function prescribed by $(\omega,x)\mapsto f(x)$. The map prescribed by $f\mapsto\hat f$ is injective.

Comment: what is $X$ and $Y$ in your definitions? To me it seems natural to get the idea of embedding such that the space of interest (the space embedded) is isomorphic to some measurable subspace of the other space. Maybe it is equivalent to what you had written, Im not sure

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry, $(X,Y)=(E_1,E_2)$.